# Python Multiprocesing async running process one after the other

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing 
import requests

def work(number):
    link = 'http://APILink/'
    response = requests.get(link).text
    print response

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    number_processes = 2
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(number_processes)
    results = pool.map_async(work, range(1,3))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Im running above code to run multiprocessing using async with 2 process. But when I run the code, its running serially but not parallely. How to run both the processes at a time parallely.

Comment: How do you know its running serially? I tried your code - it runs in parallel on my system.

Comment: When I hit the api link..it took me 4 secs, whereas when I run the script with 2 processes, it took me around 10 secs, that itself telling its running one after the other

Comment: That's probably not the most reliable method to detect serial vs. parallel. I would suggest to add some `print "begin/end worker %d" % number ` statement at the beginning/end of the worker.

Comment: begin worker 1 at  1491492137.92
begin worker 2 at  1491492137.92
end worker 2 at  4.90223908424
end worker 1 at  8.7440340519
see both the process has to complete at 4.9 seconds..but second process is taking 8.7 seconds to complete

Comment: So, it is running in parallel, but the time it takes to complete the request differs?

Comment: both are running same requests...why the time differs then..both has to complete at same time for same request right?

Answer (score -1):

You will need a pool of workers, check out:
[The docs: using a pool of workers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

check out from the docs:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(5)
def f(x):
    return x*x

p.map(f, [1,2,3])
```

you will need to map your function with a list of workers.

Be careful about demon processes in the background.

Comment: This is almost exactly what the thread starter has, except that the thread starter used map_async - a variant of map as the documentation states.